# How to save logs in a file

Tags: node.js, node-modules

I'm using express framework for my node application and using REST API to interaction.

Need to save and maintain logs for API Request and response, including some other fields too like success response, error response and API end-point.

What's best way to save logs, in a logger.log file or database?

Can anyone help me with an example i would really appreciate some help ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering there are many logger tools available on NodeJS, your best option is to use one of those for e.g.:

1. Morgan
2. Bunyan
3. Winston
4. Node-Loggly

For your question, this has your answer https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/92186/why-is-filesystem-preferred-for-logs-instead-of-rdbms

This link contains the basic code for setting up morgan. https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/morgan.html. The code below will make a .log file when you run it.

```js
var express = require("express");
var fs = require("fs");
var morgan = require("morgan");
var path = require("path");

var app = express();

// create a write stream (in append mode)
var accessLogStream = fs.createWriteStream(path.join(__dirname, "access.log"), {
  flags: "a"
});

// setup the logger
app.use(morgan("combined", { stream: accessLogStream }));

app.get("/", function(req, res) {
  res.send("hello, world!");
});

app.listen(2000);
```

Comment: Thanks!  I have seen most of them, but my question was more having an example on ... for example if I need to save the logs in a file... and I wanted some example if you ould , cause the doc isn't always clean for juniors

Answer (score 0):

You can use express middleware for logging every request like this:

https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
     console.log('Time:', Date.now())
     //make string with req and res and save to file
     next()
})
```

**Edit:**

```
app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
     //log before callback
     next();
     //log after
});
```

Comment: I want to save each action from the moment that the API is called to the moment it failed including, the name of the API and save this info on the name of the token("exampleToken").I have read the doc but i was hoping have a more clear example.

Comment: function (err, req, res, next) - you can get all params and errors on each request. If you want logging after callback you can save after next() function

Comment: Yeah i need something like this , but i don't need just logging, i need to save those logs also... can ya help  with that /

Answer (score 0):

you can use winston libary
and here is some more examples :
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-winston-to-log-node-js-applications